# How to create signed APK with apportable

Tags: android, apk, apportable

I have created a debug APK with apportable, by typing `apportable` in the directory of my xcode project.

Now I'm trying to create a signed APK with apportable for submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://docs.apportable.com/publishing.html

Long story short:

1. Create release keys in your `.android`-folder using `keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias mykey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` (or similar)
2. Build the release-app using the keys you just created: `BUILD=release ANDROID_KEYSTORE=release.keystore ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword apportable build`

Don't forget to save your keys in a safe place as your app-updates need to be signed by the same key.

Comment: That would be in your home-folder - depending what operating-system you are using. If you open a console and type `cd ~` it should take you there. Issuing a `pwd` should give you the complete path to your home-folder (something like `/home/poonanos/` or `/Users/poonanos/`)